# Drag and drop using nightwatch

Tags: node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to drag and drop the element to particular location using drag and drop in nightwatch with selenium but when i drop more than i element to same droppable it is overlapping.

```
var dragAndDrop = require('html-dnd').codeForSelectors;  
this.dragModule = function (draggable, droppable, posX, posY) {
    browser.pause(3000);
    var dndSimulateConfig = { dropOffset: [posX, posY] };
    browser
      .execute(dragAndDrop, [draggable, droppable, dndSimulateConfig])
      .pause(2000);
  };
```

It should not overlap i want in particular co-ordinates

Comment: have you installed the html-dnd using node.js

Comment: visit this github page https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/956

Comment: Its working fine but i am not able drop to paricular co-ordinates.If i drop 2 elements to same droppable its overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> locator1: can be xpath (or cssSelector) of your first element you want
>   to drag locator2: can be xpath (or cssSelector ) is where you want to
>   drop
>
> this is tried and tested code, might be you need to little modify but
>   it's working great for me.

```
return browser
    .useXpath()
    .moveToElement(locator1, XOffset1, Yoffset1)
    .pause(100) // if you want to give wait
    .mouseButtonDown(0) // press click, down
    .moveToElement(locator2, XOffset2, Yoffset2) // move to element
    .mouseButtonUp(0); // press release , up

read here docs- http://nightwatchjs.org/api and search for "moveToElement"

how to call:

myFunction moveToSpecificElement(locator, x, y) {
  return browser
  .moveToElement(locator, x, y, function (result) {
    this.assert.equal("your assertion goes here");
  });
}
```

Comment: See my code its working but i dont know why it is overlapping

Comment: I dont know the co-ordinates of draggable

Comment: I am using selectors

Answer (score 0):

I was using html-dnd version 1.2.0. So drag and drop was overlapping. Use any older version of 'html-dnd' it will work.